# Understanding the limit of a function

Tags: calculus

I've always heard that if the value of a function approaches a given limit as the value of the argument approaches a specific value, then the limit exists. But here is an example that has me confused;

Say we have $f(x) = x^2$
and we want to check: if $|x - (-1)| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$;

$\varepsilon$ is unbounded from up, so I could technically select something very large.
If I select, for example $10$, then there will be a moment where the value of $f(x)$ will reach the value of $L$, but then pass it; this will happen as $x$ approaches $-1$ from the right. The value of $f(x)$ will be larger than $L$ before $x = 1$, after that $f(x)$ will start going in the opposite direction (towards $0$). So technically, the limit shouldn't exist with such an $\varepsilon$, yet it does. Shouldn't there be a restriction on the upper bound of $\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: If for some $\varepsilon>0$ we know that $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|x-(-1)|<\delta$ then choosing $\varepsilon$ to be larger won't change the $\delta$ we can use. So the fact $\varepsilon$ can be large doesn't matter.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> Perhaps tangentially, the condition "if $|x - (-1)| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$" is not the definition of a limit. <> The definition of a limit is "For every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x - (-1)| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$." It sounds sort of the same to what's written, but isn't. Generally, phrasing definitions in your own words is a good habit. With the limit definition, however, it's important to memorize verbatim, and eventually to internalize.

Comment: What does " is unbounded from up" mean?

Comment: Missing from your question is a clear statement of the **quantifiers** associated with epsilon and delta. You want to show that "For all epsilon > 0, there exists a delta  > 0 such that whenever |x - (-1)| < delta, then |f(x) - f(-1)| < epsilon." Here delta is assumed to depend on epsilon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have your definition worded is a little misleading.  If you want to show that $$\lim_{x\to -1}x^2 = 1$$ then you need to show that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ so that if $|x - (-1)| < \delta$ then $|x^2 - 1| < \varepsilon.$

If you pick $\varepsilon = 10$ as an example you need to find a $\delta > 0$ so that if $|x + 1| < \delta$ then $|x^2 - 1| < 10$.

Now, $$|x^2 - 1| < 10 \implies |x| < \sqrt{11} \implies |x + 1| < \sqrt{11} + 1 $$

What that means is that as long as you are within $\delta = \sqrt{11} + 1$ of $x = -1$, then $f(x) = x^2$ will be within $\varepsilon = 10$ of $L = 1$.